# X-Editable can't define form in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, x-editable

I'm trying to do a column edit using angularjs & x-editable, with the form defined in the thead attribute. This works when I do the markup for each column individually, but I'm looking to define the columns using ng-repeat, which doesn't work.

It seems like the form controller doesn't get added to the scope, so the x-editable fields can't reference it using $parse(attrs.eForm)(scope); from xeditable.js

My guess is that its some kind of scope issue with the form being defined in an ng-repeat, but I'm new to angular so don't know much more than that.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwbk0aao/) showing the problem. using an ng-repeat with only one item in it, and the html is not even referencing those properties for testing purposes.

```
<td style="width: 40%">
<td ng-repeat="header in headers" style="width:40%">
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/5875/). The trick is to use table form instead of normal form when you create dynamic forms using angular xeditable :) 
`e-form="rowform"`

Link to the documentation on table form (or row editable) is [here](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This example is different, though, in that each form is part of the ng-repeat. In my example, http://jsfiddle.net/cwbk0aao/ ,  I'm trying to define each of the "awesome user" elements in an ng-repeat, with the form defined outside.

I've found its a scope issue, and modified the xEditable code to add the form to rootScope so the elements have access to each other.

Comment: Your case looks like [column editable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-column)

Comment: Close, but one major difference preventing it from working for me. I'm defining the form within a separate ng-repeat. Here's the column edit example, just took out two columns, http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/5881/ . The form at the top associated with the "name" is not in a ng-repeat. for mine, "name" will be variable, and I'll have variable about of columns, so need to define the form controller in a ng-repeat. See "works" and "doesn't work" comments on my example http://jsfiddle.net/cwbk0aao/. They get defined within two different scopes, so I had to use rootscope.

Answer (score -1):

use  `div ng-form="myngformname" editable-form`